# Writing API best practice in Cakephp

Tags: rest, api, cakephp-2.0

i am creating a web application in cakephp 2.9. it has two use,

1. To provide API access to android and Ios devices
2. To serve Web pages(Normal web applicaiton)

currently i am developing the api part , i create a webserviceController.php file and write all the Api , Now i feel like the controller is too fatty,
i dont know which is the best practice to manage API's. now my webservice controllerhave more than 2000 lines of code..

now iam planning to seperate the each api's in different controller
can anyone suggest me a good practice for writing apis in cakephp

currently my code look like

```
class WebServicesController extends Controller
 {

public $uses = null;
public $components = array('RequestHandler', 'Verification', 'AppContstant','PushNotification');
public function users()
{
    //code to get users
      //
   $this->set(array(
        'result' => $result,
        '_serialize' => 'result'
    ));
}
```

and in my route.php

```
Router::mapResources('WebServices');
Router::parseExtensions();

Router::resourceMap(array(
    array('action' => 'users', 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => false),
```

i have more around 43 api's in webserviceController,

1. How to manage API's cakephp
2. What is the best practice?
3. _serialize vs json_encode() which is fast?
4. How to versioning my API url ?

Comment: @AD7six  can uanybody answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of making an API in cakephp is print the a JSON directly from the controller and stop the rendering by die().

Official document suggests you to have an API view for the output, which is a standard MVC way and is a good practice. You can check out more here: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Maybe you can reference how Croogo implemented it, this is a Cakephp based CMS. 
They make API as a component to manage version and methods: https://github.com/croogo/croogo/blob/master/Croogo/Controller/Component/BaseApiComponent.php 
This is an example of its URL routing in format /$version/$model/$method.$format/?$parameters
http://www.example.com/croogo-2.2.2/api/v1.0/nodes/lookup.json?type=page&title=how

Answer (score 1):

Sibin Francis, You can use rest api class and include in you api controller
add following line at top

```
 App::import('Vendor', 'REST', array('file' => 'Rest.inc.php'));
 Public function yourFunctionName() {
    if ($this->request->is("post")) {  // Use your method name put/post/get/etc
        $rest = new REST();
       // Your logic here
      return $rest->response(json_encode($data), response_code);
    }
}
```

Its very easy and simple. Only you need to call vendor Rest Api class.

Comment: how can we add oauth token based security inside the default REST setup in cakephp

Comment: Add token key in your configuration and and validate user id in system on every request. validate user that user exist or not. After successful authentication further process the request.